# Is while (k >= 0 && arr[k] > 0) safe?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Is

```
while (k >= 0 && arr[k] > 0)
```

safe?

It loop when k in range and arr[k] > 0. But I don't know if this is a good practice of coding. I know that if we do this

```
while (arr[k] > 0 && k >= 0)
```

it would be a disaster.

Comment: Unless you say how you are changing `k`, it cannot be said if it is safe or not.

Comment: Also, the answer will vary wildly in a multi-threaded scenario.

Comment: With that format of a while, couldn't you use a for loop? for(int k = 20; arr.Length > k && arr[k] > 0; k--)

Comment: Also consider readability. It may save you a couple of lines of code, but how much time will a more junior developer spend figuring out what this does?...

Comment: The only thing that is safe and certain, is that if the first condition, `k >= 0` evaluates to `false`, then no attempt will be made to evaluate the second condition, and therefore `arr[k]` will not blow-up because of a negative `k`. It might go wrong for other reasons, of course.

Comment: Thank you all! Learn a lot today!

Comment: @Jeppe: Exactly, one example what can go wrong I have shown in my answer (where && and & are giving different results).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe in the fact that `&&` short circuits. If `k` is less than zero, it won't index into `arr` with it.

It might not be safe in that the body of your while loop might not decrement `k` correctly, leading to an infinite loop. Or it might not be safe if `k` is beyond `arr`'s bounds.

Comment: as an aside, have you considered LINQ? Declaratively working with collections tends to be less buggy. `SkipWhile` and `Take` might be helpful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should care also about the array size:

```
while (k >= 0 && k < arr.length && arr[k] > 0)
```

would be a safer code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a good practice. In fact, this is part of the reason why the short-circuiting  `&&` operator has been invented. The operator evaluates its subexpressions left to right, and stops when it finds a false subexpression. This is precisely what you want; the `&&` operator lets you express this in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the expression:

> while (k >= 0 && arr[k] > 0) { ... }

No, it is **not safe.**

The expression `k >= 0 && arr[k] > 0` is safe in a way that it ensures that only positive indices of `arr[k]` are used (because `&&` short-cuts values of `k < 0` and does not evaluate the second operand `arr[k] > 0` in those cases).

**But** be aware it is **not guaranteed** that the index is **running out of bounds** (e.g. for `k >= arr.length`) - and arr could also be `null`. So you can either get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` or a `NullReferenceException` - if unhandled, your application breaks.

To avoid that, use

```
if (k >=0 && arr != null) 
{   
    while (k<arr.Length && arr[k] > 0) { ... k++; }
}
```

In the code above, if `arr` is `null`, then the loop can be skipped, because there are no elements in the array. if the array length is exceeded (i.e. `k>=arr.length`), then `arr[k] > 0` is not checked anymore (thereby avoiding an exception to occur).

I have taken the invariant part of the expression `k >=0 && arr != null` out of the loop expression because it isn't necessary (and would run slower) to evaluate that in each iteration of the loop.

Same as a `for` loop:

```
if (k >=0 && arr != null) 
    for (; var k=0; k<arr.Length && arr[k] > 0; k++) { ... }
```

Note that because you aren't starting with 0, I have skipped the initialization `var k=0`, which I assume you have done somewhere outside above in your source code.

---

**Aside, some additional information** - continue reading, if you want to know some interesting details about logical operators and side effects.

In **C/C++/C#** it is important to know the difference between `&` vs. `&&`, and `|` vs. `||`: `&` and `|` evaluate the entire expression "bit-wise," while `&&` and `||` stop evaluating if the result is already clear (logical `and` cannot be `true`, if any part of the expression is `false`; logical `or` cannot be `false`, if any part of the expression is `true`).

**In some cases** however, you need the **"non-shortcut" version `&`** too. Suppose you want to convert a string array into an array of integers and you want to convert every value which can be converted, even if some cannot be converted into integer (the others should remain 0) - as in the following **Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var sArr = new string[] {"4", "2", "x", "y", "10", "11"};
    var iArr = new int[sArr.Length];
    bool bCheck = true;
    for (var i=0; i<sArr.Length; i++)
    {
        int value=0;
        // need to use & instead of && here:
        bCheck = bCheck && int.TryParse(sArr[i], out value);
        iArr[i]=value;
    };  
    if (bCheck==true) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All numbers are okay.");
    }
    foreach (var n in iArr) Console.Write(n.ToString() + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The purpose of this code is to convert the values in the string array to int one by one and store them in an integer array - if elements do not contain valid integers, then it stores the value 0 instead.

The output we're getting here is

```
4 2 0 0 0 0
```

This is not what we expected, since 10 and 11 are also valid integers and should be converted, instead we got 0 and 0 for them.

To get the result we're expecting, i.e.

```
4 2 0 0 10 11
```

we need to replace `&&` by `&` as follows:

```
bCheck = bCheck & int.TryParse(sArr[i], out value);
```

**What is the difference here?**

If you're using `&&` in the statement above, then the shortcut is done as soon as bCheck evaluates to false - which is normally correct, because then we don't have to examine the expression any more as it is impossible to be evaluated to true.

But what also happens is that since we have the shortcut, `int.TryParse` is no longer being called and hence value is not passed out of the function - all subsequent calls in the loop will evaluate to 0 regardless of the value contained in `sArr[i]`.

This is an unintended side-effect we have here, which can be fixed by enforcing to evaluate every expression (by the usage of `&`).